# AVFoundation doesn't allow to capture video in 240fps

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture

I tried so many times to capture 240fps video in the above iOS 7 version. But all attempts have been failed. My code is followings.

```
CGFloat frameRate = 240.f;

for (AVCaptureDeviceFormat *videoFormat in [self.inputCamera formats]) {
    CMFormatDescriptionRef videoFormatDescriptionRef = videoFormat.formatDescription;
    Float64 maxFrameRate = ((AVFrameRateRange *) [videoFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges objectAtIndex:0]).maxFrameRate;

    if (maxFrameRate >= frameRate && CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(videoFormatDescriptionRef) == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange) {

        if ([self.inputCamera lockForConfiguration:nil]) {

            self.inputCamera.activeFormat = videoFormat;
            [self.inputCamera setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(600.f/(CGFloat)_frameRate, 600)];
            [self.inputCamera setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(600.f/(CGFloat)_frameRate, 600)];

            [self.inputCamera unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}

AVCaptureConnection *connection = [videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ( connection ) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    if ([connection respondsToSelector:@selector(setVideoMinFrameDuration:)])
        connection.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, _frameRate);

    if ([connection respondsToSelector:@selector(setVideoMaxFrameDuration:)])
        connection.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, _frameRate);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

If I try to set frame rate to 240fps directly, it crashes. So I had to set the minimum value between the values supported by iOS and 240 fps.

Is there anyone can help me?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the maximum is 60 fps, and it depends off the capture device you selected.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW5